# Could a small group of Asgardians still be alive?

Tags: stargate

In *Stargate SG-1* the Asgard seem to have all died either through the war with the replicators or when they blew up their planet, but in *Stargate: Atlantis* we see them again in their exosuits for two episodes, but I'm pretty sure that they also died.

But is there anyway that they could be alive? Maybe just a small group in the home galaxy or an outpost that is unaware of what has happened? Or anywhere for that matter. As they did have a break off group of researchers that were exiled, because of the research they were doing on there regeneration as they were clones could they still be alive?

Also the SGC has a device that can travel to different dimensions, why not use this to go to another universe and tell the Asgard there what had happened to the Asgard in their world, and see if they wanted to go back with them to rebuild their civilization?

Answer (score 7):

The Pegasus galaxy Asgard showed up in two episodes of SG:A and weren't seen or heard from since. In those episodes, we never found out what happened to them, so it is quite possible that group is still around.

Heck, with the Wraith still in a state of civil war, the Asgard should be unmolested as long as they set-up camp in an unoccupied world and don't bother the Wraith. As long as they don't draw attention to themselves, they should be fine.

As for going to alternate realities, it's *highly* likely that in any alternate reality the Asgard have already destroyed themselves. The "safer" course of action would be to use the time machine to go back before the cloning was irreversible. However, doing that would change the entire history of the Asgard—and there is no way of knowing if the change would be for the better or worse.

Without cloning, it's impossible to tell what the lifespan of an "organic" Asgard is. They cloned themselves to expand their lives, so we know Thor wouldn't be around to become friends with O'Neill or Daniel. Which would alter the course of the SGC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, their could still be a group of Asgards left alive. However, as far as we know, after the group in the Pegasus Galaxy died, they are extinct.

Comment: Yeah its a shame the show never really told us or gave us a clue that they could still be out there, I read that they are making two new stargate movies in the next couple of years so let's hope they fill a few gaps the tv series left up

Comment: @CoreyKelly they are able to upload their conciseness, and they gave stargate command their entire database, so if they did stick themselves onto the database, they could be reborn via stargate command after they fix the genetic issues.

Comment: @himarn wow I never thought of that, it would be fantastic if they were able to bring them back like that! they could even just bring them back in new clone bodies? And then they would Abe able to figure it out for themselves....